# Simultaneously block diagonalizing two $4\times 4$ matrices?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, diagonalization

I set my self a practice problem of finding the $2D$ irreducible representation, $R_2$, of the group [$D_3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6#Summary_of_group_operations). So far I have used projection matrices to find the generators in $R_2 \oplus R_2$ to be:
$$R_2 \oplus R_2(a)=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$R_2 \oplus R_2(b)=\begin{pmatrix}0& 0&1&0\\-1&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&-1&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
I now need to simultaneously block diagonalize these matrices, but as far as I can tell there is no standard procedure to doing this. Does anyone know how it can be done in this relatively simple case?

Note: this source actually gives the $R_2(g)$ irreducible rep: [https://www.its.caltech.edu/~xcchen/img/Ph129b2017/lecture/lecture0124.pdf](https://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Excchen/img/Ph129b2017/lecture/lecture0124.pdf)

Comment: I'm confused: you are writing $R_2 \oplus R_2$ like you already have the irreducible representation $R_2$ and are building a larger space. But this is not the case, since you seem to be starting from a $4$-dimensional representation. Where did these matrices come from? (and what are the group elements $a$ and $b$?)

Comment: @Joppy Sorry I should have explained. I am writing $R_2\oplus R_2$ since I know this to the irreducible decomposition of this 4D representation. The matrices where found using the projection $P_i=\frac{dim(R_i)}{ |G|} \sum_g \chi(g)^*g$ on the group algebra. The group elements $a$ and $b$ are those given on the wikipedia page I linked to in the question. If I get chance I will edit this into the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. It's not so hard to say that the generators $a, b$ each have order $2$, then people will know what generators you are talking about. You could also write the group presentation explicitly: $\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = 1, aba = bab \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to simultaneously block diagonalize these matrices out of an educated guess looking at the eigenvectors of  $R_2\oplus R_2(a)$ and working my way from there.

---

If we define:
$$\tilde I=\begin{pmatrix} I_2&I_2\\I_2&-I_2\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&1&1\\1&-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
then the basis transformation defined thru:
$$A'=\tilde I^{-1}P^{-1}A P \tilde I$$
diagonalizes both $R_2\oplus R_2(a)$ and $R_2\oplus R_2(b)$ to give:
$$R_2\oplus R_2(a)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$R_2\oplus R_2(b)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} -0.5&0.5&0&0\\1.5&0.5&0&0\\0&0&0.5&-0.5\\0&0&-1.5&-0.5\end{pmatrix}$$
from which we can read of values for $R_2(a)$ and $R_2(b)$. Note these will be different to those given in the link in the question - but are required to be isomorphic.